# RTK implement query in createAPI headers of another API

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have two APIs. One is provided by Apple and one by my own server. In order to get the JWT token for the WeatherKitAPI provided by Apple I need to contact my server. I implemented an API for that. However, I need to have this data in the prepareHeaders of my other createApi, which I don't know how to implement:

**General API**

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';

export const generalApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'api',
    tagTypes: ['settings' ],
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: 'https://api.myapp.com/v1/',
        prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState })=> {
            const token = getState().session.token;

            if (token) {
                headers.set('authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
            }

            return headers;
        }
    }),
    endpoints: (builder)=> ({
        getWeatherKitToken: builder.query({
            query: ()=> 'getWeatherKitToken',
            providesTags: [ 'settings' ]
        }),
        login: builder.mutation({
            query: (body)=> ({
                url: 'login',
                method: 'POST',
                body: body
            }),
            invalidatesTags: [ 'settings' ]
        }),
    }),
});

export const {
    useGetWeatherKitTokenQuery,
    useLoginMutation,
} = generalApi;
```

**WeatherKit API**

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';

export const weatherKitApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'weatherKit',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: 'https://weatherkit.apple.com/api/v1/',
        prepareHeaders: (headers, {})=> {    
            /* Implement logic to get token here */
            return headers;
        }
    }),
    endpoints: (builder)=> ({
        availability: builder.query({
            query: ({ lat, lon })=> `availability/${lat}/${lon}`,
        })
    })
});

export const {
    useAvailabilityQuery
} = weatherKitApi;
```

I tried to implement the useGetWeatherKitTokenQuery directly inside the prepareHeaders but this is unfortunately not allowed.

```
prepareHeaders: async (headers, {  })=> {
    const { data: token } = await useGetWeatherKitTokenQuery();

    if (token) {
        headers.set('authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
    }

    return headers;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so first of `prepeareHeaders` function, runs before `every` request happens on current `api`. So implementing query inside `prepeareHeaders` gonna mean that you are going to run this function before every api request you do.

To make it work like that you are going to do it like so:

```js
baseQuery: (args, { signal, dispatch, getState }, extraOptions, ...additionalArgs)=> fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: 'https://weatherkit.apple.com/api/v1/',
    prepareHeaders: async (headers)=> {
        const { data } = await dispatch(generalApi.endpoints.getWeatherKitToken.initiate(undefined, { forceRefetch: true }));

        if (data?.token) {
            headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${data.token}`);
        }

        return headers;
    }
})(args, { signal, dispatch, getState }, extraOptions, ...additionalArgs),
```

Note, this is more of concept since i belive you don't want it that way.

To do that properly, you need to introduce an slice where you gonna keep your token, like that:

```js
const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState: { user: null, token: null } as AuthState,
  reducers: {},
  //  extraReducer
  },
})
```

Next thing to do is to dispatch token in there on some query:

```js
  ...
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addMatcher(
      api.endpoints.login.matchFulfilled,
      (state, { payload }) => {
        state.token = payload.token
        state.user = payload.user
      }
    )
  ...
```

next you need to update your `prepeareHeaders` function like so:

```js
 prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
     const token = (getState() as RootState).auth.token
      if (token) {
        headers.set('authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
      }
      return headers
 }
```

Lemme know if more explanations needed.
Working example [Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/tree/master/examples/query/react/authentication-with-extrareducers?from-embed)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! However, the `dispatch` is not part of the prepareHeaders params, but can be worked around. I will make an edit to your answer. Also I implemented the second recommendation already for my session handling, though I am missing the initial API call to get the weatherKitToken on your example of this.

Comment: To get token for a first time you use `useGetWeatherKitToken` in your case. And extra reducer should have matcher set to `generalApi.endpoints.getWeatherKitToken.fulfilled`

Comment: Likely you gonna need to use `skip` parameter on useQuery, `useAvailabilityQuery(params, { skip: !token })`

Comment: But then I need to implement this logic in each and every component I am using those Queries which require the token?!

Comment: Well I normally tokens are stored with redux memorise. But what I do in such conditions, is I wrap the hook inside another hook: `export const useWrappedQueryHook = (params) => { const {data:token} = useGetWeatherToken(); return useAvilibilityTokenQuery(params, { skip: !token});`

Comment: There are differences occasions (like SSR hydration) where you have to combine useQuery with some other stuff like useRouter in react, and customising rtkq hooks this way feels much more natural, then doing it thru redux internals…